# R: match according to two key variables: exact numeric variable & closest string variable

Tags: r, match, string-matching

I have two datasets containing identifiers of some of the same individuals.

`df1` is more complete and has three variables: (1) the name of the individual, (2) a regional registration id, (3) the region code where the id was registered.

`df2` only informs (1) and (2) (i.e., name and regional registration id, but not the region code).

Individuals are uniquely identified by region code *and* regional registration id. Different regions may inform the same id number. Besides, the same individual always has the *same* regional registration id across the two datasets, but may not have the exact same spelling of their name across these datasets.

I would like to add the region code to `df2` by matching each one of its rows to `df1` using as key variables the *exact* regional registration id as well as the *closest* name between the datasets (the one that has the most similar spelling). Consider the example below:

```
library("tidyverse")
          
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("flaviasillva", "flaviasilvaa", "rodrigomaia", "mariaconceicao",
                               "felipesantos", "mateussauro",
                               "flaviasilva",
                               "abrahaoemidiopedreiradealbuquerque"),
                      regional_registration_id = c(rep(1,4),
                                                   rep(2,2),
                                                   3,
                                                   4),
                      region_code = c("A", "B", "C", "D",
                                      "B", "D",
                                      "F",
                                      "Z"))
        
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("flaviasilva", "rodrigommaia", "filipesantos", "abrahaoemidiopdealbuquerque"),
             regional_registration_id = c(1, 1, 2, 4))
```

My desired output should be:

```
                         name regional_registration_id region_code
1                 flaviasilva                        1           A
2                 flaviasilva                        1           B
3                filipesantos                        2           B
4 abrahaoemidiopdealbuquerque                        4           Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `agrep` `rowwise` in dplyr. You would need to play around with the `max.distance` setting.

This approach works if you have exactly one match, otherwise it will throw an error.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(name = agrep(name,
                      df1[df1$regional_registration_id == regional_registration_id, ]$name,
                      value = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = c("name", "regional_registration_id"))

#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   name         regional_registration_id region_code
#>   <chr>                           <dbl> <chr>      
#> 1 flaviasillva                        1 A          
#> 2 felipesantos                        2 B
```

If you want to see all possible matches first, we can use the approach below. The next step would be to think about which `match_id`s to join (always the first or all ids or only ids which match another condition?):

```r
library("tidyverse")

df2 %>% 
  rowwise(name) %>%  
  summarise(
    tibble(match_name = agrep(name,
                              df1[df1$regional_registration_id == regional_registration_id, ]$name,
          value = TRUE),
          match_id = seq_len(length(match_name))),
    regional_registration_id = regional_registration_id
  )

#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'name'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#> # Groups:   name [2]
#>   name         match_name   match_id regional_registration_id
#>   <chr>        <chr>           <int>                    <dbl>
#> 1 flaviasilva  flaviasillva        1                        1
#> 2 flaviasilva  flaviasilvaa        2                        1
#> 3 filipesantos felipesantos        1                        2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks @TimTeaFan! The issue with the code you propose is that there may be more similar spelling for individuals with different `regional_registration_id` in the two datasets - who are, by definition, different individuals. There are indeed cases where different people have exactly the same name - I have updated the example to comprise this case. I would like to find the closest match on names only across individuals with same `regional_registration_id` in both `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: @PaulaSpinola See my updated answer, we can subset `df1` with `df1[df1$regional_registration_id == regional_registration_id, ]$name` to get only those names that match the `regional_registration_id`. Note that we still have to think about what should happen when more than one match is returned. At the moment my answer doesn't account for that.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have now updated the example (and the desired output) to incorporate a situation where there is more than one name in `df1` which has the same similarity score to a given name in `df2`. As you pointed out, the current code above gives us an error. Would it be possible to adjust the code to return all the matches?

Comment: @PaulaSpinola See my updated answer. We can look at all possible matches, and then the next question is: which `match_id` do you want to join.

Comment: there are actually issue with longer names (which is very common in my data). I updated the example again. I am sorry for only catching this up now.

Comment: `abrahaoemidiopedreiradealbuquerque` should match with `abrahaoemidiopdealbuquerque` (this is actually an example from my real data)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `stringdist_join`, a highly useful function from the `fuzzyjoin` package for merging dataframes based on fuzzy, or approximate, matching.

The key elements with this function are (i) the choice of a distance, or (dis-)similarity, metric and (ii) the choice of the maximum distance threshold. The metric chosen here is the Jaro-Winkler distance and the threshold is set to 0.2 (which is relatively strict given that complete similarity is 0 and complete dissimilarity is 1):

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   stringdist_join(
       ., df2,
       by  = c("name", "regional_registration_id"),
       # use left join:
       mode = 'left',
       # use Jaro-Winkler distance metric:
       method = "jw",
       # maximum distance:
       max_dist = 0.2,
       # name for distance column:
       distance_col = 'dist') %>%
  # remove rows for which no matches were found:
  filter(!is.na(name.y)) %>%
  # select relevant columns:
  select(c(4,3,5)) %>%
  # renamce columns with function:
  rename_with(~sub("\\.x|y", "", .), matches("\\.x|y"))
         name. region_code regional_registration_id.
1  flaviasilva           A                         1
2  flaviasilva           B                         1
3 filipesantos           B                         2
```